# onClick function error with typescript when build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a **submit** function on a button. But when I build the application, a typing error appears. I tried different approaches but I don't understand how to solve the error.

This is the error:

[image]

I simplified the submit function which still returns the error.

```
  const handleSubmit = ({e}: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

#another try
  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

<Button onClick={(e: any) => handleSubmit(e)} />

#another try
<Button onClick={handleSubmit} />
```

Comment: Read the error message: for whatever reason `Button` is expecting a callback function which takes no arguments.

Comment: From which library you are getting `Button` element?

Comment: One tip is if you are using Typescript, you shouldn't really use `any` but put some effort into correctly typing your code. As the `Button` element isn't a regular HTML `button`, you must check its props to understand what `onClick` expects. 

It should work by the error you posted if you remove `e: any` from your handler.

Comment: You should add more info about the `Button` component and its props. Is it custom? Is it from a library? Which one?

Comment: Try to give an opzional parameter like this: (e?: any) => .......

Answer (score -1):

Considering my comment above, something like this should work:

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    ...
    // Your handler code
  };

  <Button onClick={handleSubmit} />
```

Answer (score -2):

According to the type that you have set for 'e' in fact you did not use the typescript and you create a trick to handle typeScript error and warning so you can write like below:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

<Button onClick={handleSubmit} />
```

Comment: This won't work as the prop `onClick` expects a function with no parameters. This is what the error is about.

Comment: @RafaelFreitas onClick={handleSubmit} by default passes the event param !!!!!! :|

Comment: for a regular HTML `button` element. This is a custom `Button` element which, judging by the TS error, doesn't pass in anything to the handler.